# Modifying polygon's vertex position with Pixjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, polygon, pixi.js

Hi I'm new to pixijs (pixi.js - v5.2.4),
I have seen some [samples](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-basic/container.js) in the pixijs website ,
added a simple slider,by changing the slider value the position of a vertex of a polygon will get change [my code in codepen](https://codepen.io/Codingforpleasure/pen/YzwzaVd?editors=0001) .

```
var el = document.getElementById('slider');

if (el) {
    el.addEventListener('input', changePolygon);
    console.log("Great!!")
}
else{
    console.log("It's null!!")
    throw new ReferenceError("missingElement is not defined");
}
```

The function handler:

```
function changePolygon(e){
graphics.clear();
    var target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    console.log(target.value)

    // draw polygon  
    // flat array of numbers that will be interpreted as [x,y, x,y, ...], 
    let path = [300, 370,
                500, 370,
                500, 420, 
                target.value, 420]; 

    graphics.lineStyle(outline_thicknes, outline_color, 1);
    graphics.beginFill(0x650A5A);
   graphics.drawPolygon(path);
    graphics.endFill();

}
```

but for some reason the polygons's **outline** doesn't look well,
can somebody please take a look and suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to wrap `target.value` with **parseFloat** because `target.value` is of type string.

Now it works well!